# Filter on Name of Azure Disk Resources

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell

Hi I'm building a DevOps pipeline and trying to get a list of disks to query.

To try and make the code a bit neater, just trying to understand if there's a better way f doing this. We currently have disks named disk_2 or disk2 or disk-2. this is an example with up to 8 disks per vm. I could use

```
Get-AzDisk | ? {$_.name -like "*disk-2*" -or $_.Name -like "*disk2*" -or $_.name -like "*disk_2*"}
```

But i was thinking could i create a list, maybe something like this `$list = disk_1,disk1,disk-1,disk_2,disk2,disk-2,disk_3,disk3,disk-3,etc..`

Then reference the list in the Powershell pipeline.

```
Get-AzDisk | ? {$_.name -like "*disk-2*" -or $_.Name -like "*$list*"}
```

Thsi doesn't seem to work, this will be running in Azure DevOps in an automated pipeline.

Comment: How about `$_.name -match 'disk(-|_)?2'`  ?  ;-)

Comment: @Olaf Thanks that looks good, would I need to add all 8 possibilities for disk1 disk2 disk 3 etc?

Comment: Instead of the "2" you could use the regex for a single digit "\d"

Comment: @Olaf not the best with regex, would you mind sharng the code?

Comment: `$_.name -match 'disk(-|_)?\d'`

Comment: The array approach would also work. The condition then is `Where-Object {$list -contains $_.Name}`

Comment: And another regex approach would be this `$_.name -match 'disk[-_]?\d'`

Comment: Thanks all, think regex would be the best fit, just curious the array would be something like `$list =@(disk1,disk_1,disk-1,etc...)`  I guess. Thanks all for your help. Olaf if you post it as an answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: @Theo Wouldn't it be necessary to have the complete name as the elements of the list? I think it wouldn't work with just a part of the name, would it?

Comment: @Olaf Sure, the array should contain the full names then. This was suggested by the OP himself, I just tried to explain what the Where-Object clause would look like in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not easier to read when you're not familiar with regex but much less to type would it be like this:

```
Get-AzDisk | 
    Where-Object {$_.name -match 'disk(-|_)?\d'}
```

... or this:

```
Get-AzDisk | 
    Where-Object {$_.name -match 'disk[-_]?\d'}
```