# Can't filter resources by name in Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli

When I execute the following command (as suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-group-list-examples)):

```
az resource list --query "[?location=='swedencentral']"
```

I get a list of resource groups, as expected. One of them is named *se-tyr-business* and I see it in the listing clearly containing the following section.

> {
> "changedTime": "2023-02-21T04:41:33.593799+00:00",
> ...
> "location": "swedencentral",
> "name": "se-tyr-business",
> ...
> "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites"
> }, ...

So I figured that if I substitute *location* for *name*, then the syntax should produce a filtered list by that parameter. However, executing:

```
az resource list --query "[?name=='se-tyr-business']"
```

produces an empty list, suggesting that there's no matches. I don't understand what I'm missing. I also tried to get inspiration from [other sources](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/how-to-query-azure-resources-using-the-azure-cli/ba-p/360147) suggesting that instead of the condition in the brackets, I may simply pull out a parameter's values.

```
az resource list --query location --output table
az resource list --query name --output table
```

However, that produced no content at all (no dummy object, no empty array, nothing, nada, ziltch)! So I'm confused (and surely mistaken) as to how to continue. The official docs on listing is rahter brief and I find it hard to locate informative examples in blogs. Also, a lot of [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68209822/filter-on-name-of-azure-disk-resources) seem to target Azure Powershell, which isn't my interest.

Comment: I just tried `az resource list --query "[?name=='my-storage-account-name']"` and it worked just fine for me. Can you try the same command with some other resource name?

Comment: Are you running `az group list` or `az resource list`? Reason I ask this is because the first link you referenced in your post is for `az group list`.

Comment: @GauravMantri Oh mu God, I'm so stupid. Yes, I confused *resource* for corresponding to the concept of *resource **group***. The *resource group* is *group* in the syntax, while *resource* is just... well, **any** resource in a resource group, right? Please shoot me to death with a dirty sock for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below and followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az-resource-list):

```
az resource list --query "[?location=='swedencentral']"
```

Output:

[image]

Then used:

```
 az resource list --query "[?name=='CRLB-IP']"
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

**To get the names in particular Loaction:**

```
az resource list --query "[?location=='swedencentral'].{Name:name}"
```

Output:

[image]

```
az resource list --query "[?location=='swedencentral'].name"
```

Output:

[image]

**You can use && operator to get particular location and name:**

```
az resource list --query "[?location=='swedencentral'] && [?name=='CRLB-IP']"
```

Output:

[image]